# Which foods increase the brain activity?

Tags: nutrition, brain

Are there any foods which can increase the brain activity, and can make you instantly more "clever"?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). It would really help if you had some research of your own and specific foods or nutrients in mind - in that way we could think of a more targeted answer. We can't really give diet recommendations if that's what you are looking for. You can always [edit] your question to narrow it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if our diet can make us cleverer or not but I do know how our food habits can improve the overall functioning of the nervous tissue like memory,reflexes etc.

You see the well being of the nervous system based solely on diet tactics can be undertaken in 5 steps:

1)The neurons communicate with one another via synapses and the working rate of the synapses depends on the availability of neurotransmitter.Neurotransmiter depletion is the main cause of fatigue at the synapses.
Intake of tryptophan rich food like milk ,,egg yolk and legume help in the formation of neurotransmitter serotonin which is thought to be involved in the memory pathways.Intake of choline containing food like eggs,liver,peanuts,spinach,beet,wheat,shell fish etc helps improve acetylcholine formation.

2)The neuronal tissue is broadly segregated into white matter and grey matter.
Compounds like galactocerebrosides are more common in the white matter composition and gangliosides in the grey matter.
Intake of galactose rich food like milk,
essential fatty acids like linolenic acids,rich in walnut oil,soyabean oil,marine fish oils and linolenic acids in safflower and peanut oils help improve the functioning of these tissues.

Also amino acids like cysteine,methionine and serine are essentially helpful in maintaining the health of the nervous system.

3)The nervous system can generate ATP for conduction of impulses only from glucose.So the proper intake of glucose plays an important role too in reducing fatigue.

4)Electrolytes like Na+,K+ are important for conduction of impulses.So they should be considered for intake but in proper quantities.

5)Vitamin B1,B6 is essential for a healthy nervous system.Food like yeast,liver,cereal grains,lentils,fish are rich in both of them.

Comment: Great answer. However, since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers), in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].